# regex to extract name and email address works good in websites but not in java code

Tags: java, regex

I wrote a method to extract name and email address from a given string. I am using following regex expression

```
"FROM: (?: ?([^ ]*)?\\s)?(?:<?(.+@[^>]+)>?)"
```

In the above expression "FROM: " is kind of flag which comes before required name and email address. The issue is when I check this regex in [online tool](https://regexr.com/) then it works fine as shown below.

[image]

However, if I use this regex expression in the java 8 code then it only matches when the input string is only "FROM: aaa bbb abc@def.com". If the input string has an extra character at start or end of string then it doesn't match. Following is the code

```
public void extractNameAndEmail(String input) {
        if(input == null)
            return;
        
        String reg = "FROM: (?: ?([^ ]*)?\\s)?(?:<?(.+@[^>]+)>?)";
        
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(reg);
        
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if(matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
        
        }
```

Any suggestion what I am missing here would be very helpful.

Comment: You need to prune the extra characters first (alter your expression), or consider using `matcher.find()` rather than `matcher.matches()`, and then prune the extra characters after finding the match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From java documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

> A matcher is created from a pattern by invoking the pattern's matcher method. Once created, a matcher can be used to perform three different kinds of match operations:
>
> - The matches method attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern.
> - The lookingAt method attempts to match the input sequence, starting at the beginning, against the pattern.
> - The find method scans the input sequence looking for the next subsequence that matches the pattern.

As you can see, `matches` method will only return `true` if the whole regex matches the data.
In you case, you are trying to **find** the part of the data matching the regex, so you should use the `find` method.

So, your code should look like this:

```
public void extractNameAndEmail(String input) {
    if(input == null)
        return;

    String reg = "FROM: (?: ?([^ ]*)?\\s)?(?:<?(.+@[^>]+)>?)";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(reg);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }

}
```